# How can I see agents as a set of features?

Tags: simulation, netlogo

I'm creating an algorithm wherein I need to observe/see each agent as a set of its features (color, size, etc.). I need to do this so I can see all turtles in the environment as a set of features, so I can compare them easily. I am stumped as to how to do this in NetLogo.

Comment: What exactly does it mean to "see all turtles in the environment as a set of features"? Can you give an example?

Comment: For instance, I have two agents, one colored red and one blue. Both agents have size 1 and both is facing to the right. Instead of looking at them as turtle 0 and turtle 1, I need to see them as an array of sets of features of agent, the first array value being [red,1,right] and the second being [blue,1,right]. I just made up the whole description in square brackets just to get my point across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
observer> create-turtles 4
observer> print [(list color size heading)] of turtles
[[65 1 134] [65 1 320] [85 1 314] [45 1 100]]
```

Note that the list is in random order; if you wanted it in who number order you could do:

```
observer> print map [[(list color size heading)] of ?] sort turtles
[[85 1 314] [65 1 320] [45 1 100] [65 1 134]]
```